# UICollectionView Horizontal Scrolling Does Not Scroll Until Last Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I had an issue which is I can't scroll to my last item in a horizontal `UICollectionView`. How can I fix this problem? Below is a link to my video and my project file because it's hard to explain. Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwvEaCrhg6dTbkdTRUYwTjhNN2c/view?usp=sharing

https://youtu.be/8WVyrUl4qfQ

Here is my code for UIViewcontroller that have UICollectionView :

```
@synthesize dummyArrayImage,dummyArrayLabel,dummyDictionary,dummyArrayDescriptionLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    dummyArrayImage = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    dummyArrayLabel = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"RM 3.00",@"RM 10.00",@"RM 5.90",@"RM1.20",@"RM 8.10", nil];
    dummyArrayDescriptionLabel = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Tesco Choco Milk",@"Tesco Sardin",@"Ayam Goreng",@"Ikan Pari",@"Itik", nil];
    dummyDictionary = @{@"image":dummyArrayImage, @"label":dummyArrayLabel, @"description":dummyArrayDescriptionLabel};

    NSLog(@"dummy dictionary : %@", dummyDictionary);
    NSLog(@"dummy array : %@", dummyArrayImage);
    NSLog(@"dummy array count : %d", (int)dummyArrayImage.count);
    NSLog(@"dummy dictionary count : %d", (int)dummyDictionary.count);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return dummyArrayImage.count;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    TezCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *contentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:dummyArrayImage[indexPath.row]];

    cell.contentImageView.image = contentImage;
    cell.titleLabel.text = dummyArrayDescriptionLabel[indexPath.row];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = dummyArrayLabel[indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: this is because of UIEdgeInsets , or section insets , probably you have wrong configuration

Comment: add some code here , may be your  collection view content view issue, Please paste some code here ,,,

Comment: @Mohamad Afiq   Select your view controller in storyboard and uncheck the option "Adjust Scroll View Insets"  and tell me if u got still same problem.

Comment: @bhavinramani I tried your suggestion but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @MohamadAfiq have u set any auto layout?

Comment: @bhavinramani yup, I'm using autolayout in my UIViewController.

Comment: I added project file. Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out by my own. This problem happened because I'm using autolayout. I tried to play with autolayout constraint and suddenly it's working as expected. Thank you for all those whose answered my question. You guys rock. Cheers.

Comment: absolutely, your constrain not set proper so the collection view not display last cell .

Answer (score 1):

add Top, Bottom Trailing and Leading Constraint in UICollectionView has solved the problem for me!

Comment: thank you same problem,cause i use auto layout